# Prevent click:row event on text selection on row

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When text is selected in a [v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) row, the [click:row](http://click:row) event is fired.
Is there any way to prevent this?

#### Replicate sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-nightingale-fbyk2

**Instructions**

- *Select any value in the table and watch the console*

Comment: Why do you want that? There might be a better solution, if we know your intentions.

Comment: @tauzN I do update the route on row click. It's very annoying that the route gets updated when I just want to select a text in the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be to check if there was some selected text at the time you clicked. Your `rowClick` method would be:

```js
    rowClick(item) {
      if (window.getSelection().toString()) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(item);
    }
```